# how to validate tinymce textarea for preceding and trailing white-spaces?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to validate tinymce content. But it accepting trailing and white-spaces. Beacause when user enter blank spaces it takes with paragraph tag `<p>   </p>` like this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that there needs to be a space character inside the paragraph in order to be able to click in it.
You can verify this using FF and the tinymce code plugin (press the button labeled "html") and remove the space character. You won't be able to click into the paragraph afterwards.

A solution to this can be to clean the generated source code afterwards and remove the spaces before saving the contents to db.

Comment: Thanks,I am trying your solutions.